# Rendering two separate objects, one object does not appear on screen

Tags: opengl, rendering, shader

I'm trying to create random terrain, surrounded by a skybox, which I will then apply a texture to. I have 2 shader programs running interchangeably but I can't seem to make the skybox appear on screen, whereas the terrain is rendered normally.

The terrain is essentially a grid on the x-z plane and every vertex has a y value generated by a noise algorithm. The grid is square and has a side of `SIDE`. I have centered the terrain by using an offset on the `x` and `z` values, equal to `SIDE/2`.

The skybox is a cube which also has a side `SIDE`, so it should fit perfectly with the grid inside it, and should be visible since the `y` values of the terrain's vertices are small compared to `SIDE` or even `SIDE/2`.

This is the code:

```
GLfloat skyboxVertices[24] = {
    -HALF_SIDE, HALF_SIDE, -HALF_SIDE,   //A = 1
    HALF_SIDE, HALF_SIDE, -HALF_SIDE,    //B = 2
    HALF_SIDE, -HALF_SIDE, -HALF_SIDE,   //C = 3
    -HALF_SIDE, -HALF_SIDE, -HALF_SIDE,  //D = 4
    -HALF_SIDE, HALF_SIDE, HALF_SIDE,    //E = 5
    HALF_SIDE, HALF_SIDE, HALF_SIDE,     //F = 6 
    HALF_SIDE, -HALF_SIDE, HALF_SIDE,    //G = 7
    -HALF_SIDE, -HALF_SIDE, HALF_SIDE    //H = 8
};


//generating & binding skybox VAO
glGenVertexArrays(1, &skyboxVAO);
glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);

//creating & binding VBO for skybox vertices
glGenBuffers(1, &skyboxVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, skyboxVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxVertices),
    skyboxVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


//3 indices per triangle, 2 triangles per side, 6 sides for a cube
//for a total of 36 
totalSkyboxElements = 36;

GLuint skyboxElements[36]{
    0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, //front
    4, 5, 1, 1, 0, 4, //up
    4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, //back
    7, 6, 3, 3, 2, 7, //bottom
    1, 5, 6, 6, 3, 1, //right
    0, 4, 7, 7, 2, 0  //left
};

//creating & binding VBO for skybox vertices
glGenBuffers(1, &skyboxElementsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, skyboxElementsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxElements),
    skyboxElements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The code of the vertex and fragment shaders are as follows, and are compiled and linked without errors:

```
//vertex shader
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}

//fragment shader
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
   color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Finally, in the mainloop the code is as follows. `shaderProgramSB` refers to the skybox and `shaderProgram` refers to the terrain

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(shaderProgramSB);
glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, totalSkyboxElements, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

glBindVertexArray(terrainVAO);

camera->update();
projectionMatrix = camera->projectionMatrix;
viewMatrix = camera->viewMatrix;
modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
MVP = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);


glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, totalElements, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

I have tried rendering the terrain first and the skybox after, but the result is always the same. Terrain rendered normally, skybox not rendered at all. I've been searching and searching but can't seem to locate the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The indices of the `skyboxElements` have to start at 0 and not at 1. What is `HALF_SIDE`? Do you use [face culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling)? If you want to draw the skybox on the far plane then `gl_Position = position.xyww;` (face culling enabled).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh my, i totally missed that the indices have to start from 0. Unfortunately this still doesn't fix it... `HALF_SIDE` is a constant equal to the `SIDE/2` quantity i mentioned above. I use it to put the center of the cube on `(0,0,0)`. No i'm not using face culling.

Comment: The near and far plane of the view volume - clip space. The sky box is not in the clip space, because you don't use a projection matrix. Set  `HALF_SIDE = 1.0` or use a projection matrix for the sky box

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh, forgive my ignorance, it's not the first thing that pops to my head when i hear near and far. `position` is a `vec3` object though, that means there's no w to it. Could there be any other option i might have enabled that's causing the skybox to not be rendered?

Comment: If you don't use a projection matrix, the all the coordinates have to be in normalized device space a cube from (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1) else they will be clipped. Try `gl_Position = position.xyww;`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Using the same `MVP` for both the terrain and the skybox seemed like a viable option but it doesn't seem to do the trick. `gl_Position = position.xyww` throws a compilation error because `position` is `vec3` and doesn't have a homogenous coordinate. Thank you so much for the advice though, it will help me for future projects

Comment: Then of course `gl_Position = position.xyzz`